# Using Flexbox to align items inside or wrap items 2 by 2

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to align each item in the flexbox and somehow I cannot wrap them around two by two. I have boxes with an image on the left side, and the text on the right. I tried things such as `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap` or changing the width, and other suggested ways online, but it does not change anything at all. It stays the same as 1 x 4, no matter what. How can I solve this issue? Below is my code:

```css
.secondContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.flex-item {
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.flex-item img{
    flex-grow:0;
    flex-shrink:0;
}
```

```html
<section>
            <div class="secondContainer">
                <div class="flex-item">
                    <img src="images/books/holiday/giving_thanks.png" alt="giving Thanks" class="image">
                        <div class="text">
                            <ul>
                                <li> Giving Thanks </li>
                                <li> By: Sarah Kim </li>
                                <li> ISBN Number: ISBN123123412 </li>
                                <li> Price: $9.99 </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="flex-item">
                    <img src="images/books/holiday/southern_living.png" alt="Southern Living" class="image">
                    <div class="text">
                        <ul>
                            <li> Giving Thanks </li>
                            <li> By: Sarah Kim </li>
                            <li> ISBN Number: ISBN123123412 </li>
                            <li> Price: $9.99 </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="flex-item">
                    <img src="images/books/holiday/giving_thanks.png" alt="givingThanks" class="image">
                    <div class="text">
                        <ul>
                            <li> Giving Thanks </li>
                            <li> By: Sarah Kim </li>
                            <li> ISBN Number: ISBN123123412 </li>
                            <li> Price: $9.99 </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="flex-item">
                    <img src="images/books/holiday/giving_thanks.png" alt="givingThanks" class="image">
                    <div class="text">
                        <ul>
                            <li> Giving Thanks </li>
                            <li> By: Sarah Kim </li>
                            <li> ISBN Number: ISBN123123412 </li>
                            <li> Price: $9.99 </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </section>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify how the flex items grow or shrink, give them all the same `flex` number:

```css
.flex-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1; /* <-- add this line */
}
```

> **Docs:** The `flex` CSS shorthand property sets how a flex item will grow or shrink to fit the space available in its flex container.

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

```css
.secondContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.flex-item img {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="secondContainer">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <img src="images/books/holiday/giving_thanks.png" alt="giving Thanks" class="image">
      <div class="text">
        <ul>
          <li> Giving Thanks </li>
          <li> By: Sarah Kim </li>
          <li> ISBN Number: ISBN123123412 </li>
          <li> Price: $9.99 </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item">
      <img src="images/books/holiday/southern_living.png" alt="Southern Living" class="image">
      <div class="text">
        <ul>
          <li> Giving Thanks </li>
          <li> By: Sarah Kim </li>
          <li> ISBN Number: ISBN123123412 </li>
          <li> Price: $9.99 </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item">
      <img src="images/books/holiday/giving_thanks.png" alt="givingThanks" class="image">
      <div class="text">
        <ul>
          <li> Giving Thanks </li>
          <li> By: Sarah Kim </li>
          <li> ISBN Number: ISBN123123412 </li>
          <li> Price: $9.99 </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item">
      <img src="images/books/holiday/giving_thanks.png" alt="givingThanks" class="image">
      <div class="text">
        <ul>
          <li> Giving Thanks </li>
          <li> By: Sarah Kim </li>
          <li> ISBN Number: ISBN123123412 </li>
          <li> Price: $9.99 </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: flex:2 doesn't tell anything about the number of element per row ... any value will do the same. You can try 1 or 999, you will get the same result as long as the value is the same for all the elements

Comment: I have a question, so when I somehow make the image size smaller, it becomes 3 x 1, not 2 x 2. Can I fix it to always only 2 images per row?

Comment: @sarahkim experiment with setting the value of `flex` to a `px` value (e.g. `100px`), and give the flex items width in the CSS. Play around with the values until it becomes 2x2 again. In HTML and CSS there is rarely a "magic value" that works for all variations of a layout, it will need some fiddling about to get right.

Comment: Thank you, I will try!!

Answer (score 1):

The flex attribute is missing:

```
.flex-item {
  display: flex;
  flex: 2;
```